# Issue with formula including LARGE() + multiple criterias

Tags: excel, excel-formula

At the moment my formula looks for a LARGE number in column D, which is greater than number in K4, however if the number in K4 is greater than the LARGEST number in col D I get an error `#NUM!`

```
=IF(AND($K$4="",$D$5=""),"Not Reported",IF(AND($K$4="",$D$5<>""),"Missing DATA",IF(AND($K$4<>"",$D$5<>""),INDEX($E$5:$E$23,MATCH((SMALL($D$5:$D$23,COUNTIF($D$5:$D$23,""&$K$4)+1)),$D$5:$D$23,0),1))*1-$K$4/SUM(LARGE($D$5:$D$23,COUNTIF($D$5:$D$23,">"&$K$4)+1)+SMALL($D$5:$D$23,COUNTIF($D$5:$D$23,""&$K$4)+1))))+INDEX($E$5:$E$23,MATCH("P98",$A$5:$A$23,0)))))
```

Can you advise how to alter it, so if the above occurs, instead of taking the number from K4 into consideration, simply replace it with whatever the LARGEST number in col D is and finish the rest of calculations [embedded in the formula]. Appreciate your help.

PS. IFERROR is not an option (it doesn't solve this)

SAMPLE DATA [where the error occurs]:

VALUE OF $K$4

```
250000
```

COLUMN A

```
PERCENTILE
P10
P20
P30
P40
P50
P60
P70
P80
P90
P91
P92
P93
P94
P95
P96
P97
P98
P99
P100
```

COLUMN D

```
NUMBER
3500
4096.79
10000
13500
15000
18299.46
25000
39000
50000
50000
50000
50000
200000
200000
200000
200000
200000
200000
200000
```

COLUMN E

```
VOLUME
2
2
1
2
1
2
2
1
2
0
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: This Q badly needs sample data together with expected results that no one has to retype.

Comment: I thought of that as well. Let me upload it. Thanks

Comment: `MAX` will tell you what the LARGEST number is in a range.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: If the answer below doesn't solve your problem, please see links above and [edit] your question (including that data you just added) in line with the sites posting rules & suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this works for me:

`=IF($J$4="",F27,(IF(J4>=MAX(B5:B23),(INDEX($C$5:$C$23,MATCH((SMALL($B$5:$B$23,COUNTIF($B$5:$B$23,"<"&IF(J4>MAX(B5:B23),MAX(B5:B23),J4))+1)),$B$5:$B$23,0),1))*(1-((IF(J4>MAX(B5:B23),MAX(B5:B23),J4))/SUM(LARGE($B$5:$B$23,COUNTIF($B$5:$B$23,">"&(IF(J4>MAX(B5:B23),MAX(B5:B23),J4)))+1)+SMALL($B$5:$B$23,COUNTIF($B$5:$B$23,"<"&(IF(J4>MAX(B5:B23),MAX(B5:B23),J4)))+1))))+INDEX($C$5:$C$23,MATCH("P98",$A$5:$A$23,0),1),IF(J4<=MIN(B5:B23),INDEX($C$5:$C$23,MATCH((SMALL($B$5:$B$23,COUNTIF($B$5:$B$23,">"&IF(J4<MIN(B5:B23),MIN(B5:B23),J4))+1)),$B$5:$B$23,0),1))*(1-((IF(J4<MIN(B5:B23),MIN(B5:B23),J4))/SUM(LARGE($B$5:$B$23,COUNTIF($B$5:$B$23,"<"&(IF(J4<MIN(B5:B23),MIN(B5:B23),J4)))+1)+SMALL($B$5:$B$23,COUNTIF($B$5:$B$23,">"&(IF(J4<MIN(B5:B23),MIN(B5:B23),J4)))+1))))+INDEX($C$5:$C$23,MATCH("P98",$A$5:$A$23,0),1),(INDEX($C$5:$C$23,MATCH((SMALL($B$5:$B$23,COUNTIF($B$5:$B$23,"<"&$J$4)+1)),$B$5:$B$23,0),1))*(1-($J$4/SUM(LARGE($B$5:$B$23,COUNTIF($B$5:$B$23,">"&$J$4)+1)+SMALL($B$5:$B$23,COUNTIF($B$5:$B$23,"<"&$J$4)+1))))+INDEX($C$5:$C$23,MATCH("P98",$A$5:$A$23,0),1)))))`

I had to also hedge against the K4 (or J4) value being `<MIN(B5:B23)`

Answer (score 1):

I can't give an exact answer since I don't have exact detail about what you're trying to do, however it sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
=max(k4, d:d)
```

So: If `K4` is the same are bigger than the largest number in `Column D`, then use `K4`.  Otherwise, use the biggest number in `Column D`.

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [MAX Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/max-function-e0012414-9ac8-4b34-9a47-73e662c08098)
- [MAX vs MAXA vs LARGE and MIN vs MINA vs SMALL Functions in Excel](https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-max-maxa-large-min-mina-small-functions/)

Comment: Hi ashleedawg, I have uploaded sample data.

Comment: Try my solution.  You may have to adapt it since I don't know what your spreadsheet looks like.

Comment: Doesn't your formula essentially say `=max(k4, d:d)` ?

Comment: Why yes, yes it does.  That's it, I need some sleep, signing off....  Feel free to edit.   :-)